Screen flickers
I have dell Inspiron 15 3000 3584 with the following specifications 12GB of RAM, 256GB of M.2 SSD and 1TB of HDD. I made my system dual boot first with 22.0 LTS but I noticed that my screen flickers quite a lot. I thought upgrading to 24LTS would make a difference but nothing changed. Also shifting to the other OS is takes very long time several attempts to show the DELL screen. And when it boots up it says no memory was detected on previous boot. I checked all the hardware by BIOS diagnostic but nothing seemed to be bad.
Edit(29/10/24 12:10AM IST):
Basically, there are two problems but let's just focus on one as of now. I noticed that my screen started to flicker on 22LTS and I got to know about the newly released 24LTS so I thought I might be solved on an update but it didn't work and the issue persisted.

Flickering video

I'm new here and still learning how to ask questions clearly. I’ve attached a video to help explain my question better. Please ask any follow-up questions if any.

Welcome to ASK. However it is not clear what the question is. Are you asking about the graphics flicker? Are you asking about installing 24.04LTS? You seem to be saying 24.04 is successfully installed  (shifting to other OS) but its taking a long time to install? What is the DELL screen? Is that the BIOS boot menu perhaps? You need to be more precise and with lots of backup details and preferably exact copied details (formatted) of error messages. We need something to work from.

@david I updated the original question.

The first problem is solved:
What worked for me: opened the laptop, pulled both the RAM from the slots and cleaned the RAM pins pad with an eraser and inserted it back. It just worked fine without any BIOS memory warning.
